# Inconsistent move in debug and release configurations while passing unique_ptr around?

Tags: c++, sockets, rvalue, stdmove

So I got some code handling some simple tcp sockets using the SFML Library. Thereby a socket is created under the usage of SFML capabilities and returned from a function as an rvalue reference.
An organizing function then passes this socket on ( to currently only be stored ) and signals its caller whether a socket was processed or not. This however does not work as expected.

```
struct TcpSocket : public ::sf::TcpSocket {};

unique_ptr<TcpSocket>&& TcpListener::nonBlockingNext() 
{
    unique_ptr<TcpSocket> new_socket (new TcpSocket) ;
    listener.setBlocking(false);
    if( listener.accept(*new_socket) == ::sf::Socket::Status::Done) 
    {
        new_socket->setBlocking(false);
        std::cout << "Connection established! " << new_socket.get() << "\n";
        return std::move(new_socket);
    }
    return std::move( unique_ptr<TcpSocket>(nullptr) );
}

bool ConnectionReception::processNextIncoming()
{
    unique_ptr<TcpSocket> new_socket (listener.nonBlockingNext());
    std::cout << " and then " << new_socket.get() << "\n";
    if( !new_socket ) return false;

    processNewTcpConnection( ::std::move(new_socket) );
    return true;
}
```

The afore used class of `TcpListener` encapsulates a sf::TcpListener in composition and simply forwards its usage.

I have a simple test, that attempts a connection.

```
TEST(test_NetworkConnection, single_connection)
{
    ConnectionReception reception;

    reception.listen( 55555 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 50ms );

    TcpSocket remote_socket;
    remote_socket.connect( "127.0.0.1", 55555 );

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 10ms );
    EXPECT_TRUE( reception.processNextIncoming() );
}
```

This test fails differently in both configurations I am compiling it.
In debug ( `g++ -g3` ) the test is failing unexpectedly.

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from test_NetworkConnection
[ RUN      ] test_NetworkConnection.single_connection
Connection established! 0x6cf7ff0
 and then 0
test\test_NetworkConnection.cpp:24: Failure
Value of: reception.processNextIncoming()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] test_NetworkConnection.single_connection (76 ms)
[----------] 1 test from test_NetworkConnection (78 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (87 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_NetworkConnection.single_connection

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Debugging and output shows, that the first return of `nonBlockingNext()`, the one that returns an accepted socket by the listener, has been reached, but in the subsequent outer function of `processNextIncoming` the value of `new_socket` is not set/is `nullptr`.

In Release, that is with `g++ -O3` the output shows promise, but the test itself crashes with a segfault, seemingly in test-teardown, maybe when freeing sockets, which I determined through further outputs, as debugging in optimized code is not very fruitfull.

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from test_NetworkConnection
[ RUN      ] test_NetworkConnection.single_connection
Connection established! 0xfe7ff0
 and then 0xfe7ff0
```

I further have noticed while debugging in the -g3 compilation, that the construction of `new_socket` in 'nonBlockingNext()' is seemingly reached again before returning:

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, network::TcpListener::nonBlockingNext (this=0x640f840)
    at test/../src/NetworkConnection.hpp:40
40          unique_ptr<TcpSocket> new_socket (new TcpSocket) ;
(gdb) n
41          listener.setBlocking(false);
(gdb)
42          if( listener.accept(*new_socket) == ::sf::Socket::Status::Done)
(gdb)
44              new_socket->setBlocking(false);
(gdb)
45              std::cout << "Connection established! " << new_socket.get() << "\n";
(gdb)
Connection established! 0x6526340
46              return std::move(new_socket);
(gdb)
40          unique_ptr<TcpSocket> new_socket (new TcpSocket) ;                <<<<<<--------- here
(gdb)
49      }
(gdb)
network::ConnectionReception::processNextIncoming (this=0x640f840) at test/../src/NetworkConnection.hpp:79
79          std::cout << " and then " << new_socket.get() << "\n";
(gdb)
 and then 0
80          if( !new_socket ) return false;
(gdb)
```

A step, that is most likely optimized away in a release configuration or could just be gdb being weird.

What is going wrong? How do I proceed and get this to work? Did I make any mistakes with the rvalues and moves?

Comment: No idea what's going on here, but +1 for making and reporting your debugging efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have undefined behavior here:

```
unique_ptr<TcpSocket>&& TcpListener::nonBlockingNext() 
{
    unique_ptr<TcpSocket> new_socket (new TcpSocket) ;
    //...
    if( /*...*/) 
    {
        //...
        return std::move(new_socket);
    }
    //...
}
```

The problem is that you are returning a reference to a local variable (`new_socket`). Don't be distracted by it being an rvalue reference - it is still a reference! You should return `unique_ptr` by value instead. And, even though it is legal to `std::move()` the value you are returning, it is useless at best or misses an optimization at worst - so make it just `return new_socket`.

Comment: The bit about it still being a reference eluded me. You opened my eyes in that regard. The tests pass now. I do not see however, how returning unique_ptr by value is even possible. Is it not explicitly not copy-constructible? Or is here then a move-constructor implicitly called?

Comment: Yes, both return statement and `unique_ptr<TcpSocket> new_socket (listener.nonBlockingNext());` call move constructor,

Comment: @Eugene Please consider adding this extension to your answer.